# Creating Class instances in Unity at runtime

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I want to create X objects in a loop, access and set properties of newly created objects. I've used the `Instantiate` method with a passed RigidBody, like shown in the tutorial, but I need to access the properties of the script connected to the object, not just it's rigid body.

Here's the method I'm trying to make work:

```
public void makeGrid(int w = 10, int h = 10)
{
    gridWidth = w;
    gridHeight = h;

    int tileArrayLength = gridWidth * gridHeight;
    tileArray = new Tile[tileArrayLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < gridWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridHeight; j++)
        {
            // add tiles
            Tile t = new Tile(); // !!! doesn't work >_<
            t.posX = i;
            t.posY = j;
            t.id = j + 10 * i;

            tileArray[t.id] = t;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create X objects in a loop, access and set properties of
>   newly created objects.

You can create prefabs through the editor and then instantiate them, or explicitely create a `GameObject` and attach the components you need to it:

```
GameObject prefabInstance = GameObject.Instantiate(Resource.Load("path_to_prefab")) as GameObject;

GameObject instanceThroughReference = GameObject.Instantiate(aReferenceToAnInstantiableObject) as GameObject;

GameObject emptyGameObject= new GameObject("empty game object");
```

For what concern:

> I've used the Instantiate method with a passed RigidBody, like shown
>   in the tutorial, but I need to access the properties of the script
>   connected to the object, not just it's rigid body.

With property I think you mean `Components` attached to the `GameObject` instantiate.
Either if you instantiate an object from a reference or loading through [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html), if the original GameObject has the Component you want attached to it you can retrieve them using [GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) method, or catching the return value of AddComponent.

If you are creating an empty `GameObject` you have to attach explicitely the `Components` you need:

```
GameObject go = new GameObject("foo");
Bar bar = go.AddComponent<Bar>(); //where Bar extends MonoBehavior
```